# setState of Undefined & User Authentication Error. Tried .bind(this). Tried fatpipe... Can't get it working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I have two problems actually.  First thing is that using componentWillMount or componentDidMount with a check for user will return asynchronous as it goes to firebase to check current user, and the if statement will not run as there is no user.  I tried to solve this with a Promise, but maybe my understanding of a Promise isn't good so I gave up on that and tried to work with the inner code.  I substituted the Mount with a componentWillUpdate as that seems to run multiple times so that I could forcefully bypass the error and check if the state is changed correctly.

This leads me to my second problem.  My setState says undefined.  I've read on Stack Overflow and tried to use ".bind(this)" and the fatpipe, but neither are working.  Perhaps I'm putting it in the wrong place or my syntax is wrong.  Anyone can help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Search from './Search'
import Recipe from './Recipe'
import fire from '../fire'
//import firebase from 'firebase'

class Favourites extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            recipes: []
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        var user = fire.auth().currentUser;

        if(user) {
            console.log('Favorites: requesting favorites');
            fire.database().ref('/favourites/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                var recipes_obj = snapshot.val();
                let recipes = [];
                for (let id in recipes_obj) {
                    let recipe = recipes_obj[id];
                    recipe.id = id;
                    recipes.push(recipe);
                    console.log("recipes: ", recipes)
                }
                console.log("recipes outside", recipes);
                this.setState({ recipes: recipes });
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Favorites: no user')
        }
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div>


                <div className="wrapper">


                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s12">
                                {console.log(this.recipes.bind(this))}
                                {/*{this.recipes.map( recipe => {*/}
                                    {/*return (*/}
                                        {/*<div key={recipe.id}>*/}
                                            {/*{recipe.title}*/}
                                        {/*</div>*/}
                                    {/*)*/}
                                {/*})}*/}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="container" id="search">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s12">
                                <Recipe/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default Favourites;
```

Here is attempt 2 for the Promise:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var user = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(fire.auth().currentUser).then(() => {
            if(user) {
                console.log('Favorites: requesting favorites');
                fire.database().ref('/favourites/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                    var recipes_obj = snapshot.val();
                    let recipes = [];
                    for (let id in recipes_obj) {
                        let recipe = recipes_obj[id];
                        recipe.id = id;
                        recipes.push(recipe);
                        console.log("recipes: ", recipes)
                    }
                    console.log("recipes outside", recipes);
                    this.setState({ recipes: recipes });
                }.bind(this));
            } else {
                console.log('Favorites: no user')
            }
        })

    })
```

Comment: `console.log(this.recipes.bind(this))` should be `console.log(this.state.recipes)` also I would use componentWillMount() since it would run before render()

Comment: In fact all of the commented out calls should be calling this.state.recipes not this.recipes

Comment: I've tried that console log with the bind and without the bind.  Neither works.  The main issue that still comes up is the setState says that it's undefined.  I tried it with setState({ recipes }) and with the current.  Neither seem to work.

For the commented out ones, I've tried it with this.state as well.  But the main issue still seems to be the setState.

As for componentWillMount, the issue I have there is correct Promise syntax.  I read up on it and tried it, but it's not working for me for some reason.  I used WillUpdate so that I could run through the setState issue first.

Comment: Oh, I should also note that all the console.logs at the top for recipes is correct.  I get Objects returned inside the recipes array after the push into the recipes array.

Comment: try binding this to the promise function as in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does doing the following help? (bind this to the function in promise)

```
            fire.database().ref('/favourites/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            var recipes_obj = snapshot.val();
            let recipes = [];
            for (let id in recipes_obj) {
                let recipe = recipes_obj[id];
                recipe.id = id;
                recipes.push(recipe);
                console.log("recipes: ", recipes)
            }
            console.log("recipes outside", recipes);
            this.setState({ recipes: recipes });
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Yes!  This works!  I was able to set the state with this!!   However, I'm still having issues with the user, as when the component mounts, it instantly goes to the else function.  I'm writing a promise again, but it's still failing...

Comment: what is the value of user? also at this point you really should change to componentWillMount() as for syntax just leave it the same for now

Comment: The value of user should be undefined when it first runs because it needs to go to firebase to check the user first.  Therefore the if statement gets ignored as user is undefined and it goes to the else statement.  It's not till after it goes to the else that firebase returns with the current user.  So I'm trying to make it a promise so that the user gets returned first BEFORE running the if statement.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I have already changed it to componentWillMount() as I have confirmed that the setState works.

Comment: oh then what you want to do is just wrap the entire if/else in the promise for firebase auth. somthing like user.then(user) {}

Comment: Yes I was trying that, but perhaps my syntax is wrong.

Comment: why not post your attempt?

Comment: you still have to bind this to that new (outer) promise too